# A contextual autocomplete for the power user - implementation advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I'm building a command line using jqueryUI autocomplete that builds out a sentence one phrase at a time (TAB to go to next phrase would copy the text to some other container and clear the input for the next phrase).

Each phrase can be either selected from the autocomplete or be completely arbitrary (no matches is still a valid phrase). However, when a phrase is selected I need to the know which one it was (was it selected from the autocomplete or arbitrary).

The problem is  a power user that already knows and expects certain autocomplete options to return may simple type a phrase they know will come back and hit TAB very fast before the AJAX request has a chance to return, forcing me to mark the phrase as "arbitrary" until the request returns, which is incorrect and causes some buggy behavior.

I can flag it as arbitrary temporarily and then go back and change it if it matches anything returned in the response but this is not user friendly because it may invalidate everything the user did after (since phrases are contextual), while the request was processing.

I'm guess I should cache the autocomplete list in a JS variable and match input against that list, this way it will be a synchronous lookup rather than a request (I would continue to make the requests though, updating the cached object on each keypress)

It doesn't seem like this will be bulletproof (consider how a backspace may cause it to go out of sync if the request takes too long you'll be matching against a list that has less options than it should; until the request returns a new list with looser constraints).

I'm not looking for a definite answer but just some advice on the most effecient way to implement this because it's proving very tricky.

Things like lookup data structure? at what size I be concerned about look up performance ? maybe you can think of a way to make it bulletproof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need up-to-date, async searches on word matches? Requesting the possible operations, and their subtasks/options (like `git pull`) seems like it'd be a relatively small set, and storing a cache that's referenced while typing synchronously will feel snappy. This object can be quite large, and you would be fine.

If you need fresh look up data, what you recommend sounds pretty good. Be sure to use something like [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) to only send requests when the user stops typing for a second, and an indicator that a look up is now occuring (a [little ajax spinner](http://www.ajaxload.info/) usually gets that across), and can be cached for future uses, assuming this dynamic content wouldn't then be removed somehow.